# Label a word as a pre-built entity in Microsoft LUIS

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I am creating a bot with Microsoft LUIS and I realize it is not very good with pre-built date-time entities.

Is there a way for me to explicitly label a word as a pre-built entity so that, at least for my application, I get the correct result?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Create a new entity. Keep in mind that your model has not yet been trained to recognize words as this entity. You can train your model to do so by suggesting new utterances and tagging the word as the entity. You can tag the word by clicking on it and selecting an entity. You also must keep training your model with different utterances before it'll start identifying the correct entity for each intent.

I don't have enough reputation yet to post images, but here is a reference to look at if you're lost.

[image]

Comment: Thats not what I was asking. I understand that I can always manually train, instead of using the pre-built entities. But I want to leverage the pre-built entities, and train them further so as to tune them as per my requirement. It would be great if I could just mark a word and select it as an entity which is of the type pre-built.

Comment: My apologies for misunderstanding your question. There isn't currently a way to do what you're asking unfortunately. A possible alternative would be to define a composite entity which matches your needs.